# Access a member variable from a private method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, private-methods

lick() is a private method of Cat. Unfortunately, Cat's this.paw is not accessible in lick(). Is there a simple way to create a private method that has access to the member variables of its containing class?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<p id="catStatus">???</p>
<script>
function Cat() {

    this.paw;

    var lick = function() {
        alert(this.paw);
        if(this.paw == "sticky") {
            alert("meow");
            document.getElementById("catStatus").innerHTML = "*Slurp*";
        }
    };

    this.beCat = function() {
        this.paw = "sticky";
        lick();
    }
}
var kitty = new Cat();
kitty.beCat();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` depends on how you call the method.
Since you're not calling the method on the object instance, `this` becomes the global object.

Instead, you need to save `this` in a variable:

```
function Cat() {
    this.paw = ...;

    var me = this;

    var lick = function() {
        alert(me.paw);
        if(me.paw == "sticky") {
            alert("meow");
            document.getElementById("catStatus").innerHTML = "*Slurp*";
        }
    };

    this.beCat = function() {
        this.paw = "sticky";
        lick();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, `this` does not refer to the global object within lick(), it refers to the lick function itself.

Comment: Honest question: why did you add ellipsis to the declaration of this.paw? Declaring this.paw without a value prevents an exception when referencing the variable. this.paw = ...; produces a syntax error. Maybe I should use this.paw = undefined; instead.

Comment: @andersand It would make since to me that `this` would refer to lick inside lick, but if you `alert(this.toString())` inside `lick`, it actually says "[object Window]", which is the same thing it says in a `<script>` tag outside any function so I think that's the global object. Inside beCat on the other hand, it says "[object Object]". I think this is because lick has not been instantiated with `new`. (I only tried this in Firefox.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to solve this. The problem is that the context inside of lick is not the instance of cat. You can either:

Use the call method to set the context

```
this.beCat = function() {
    this.paw = "sticky";
    lick.call(this);
};
```

or use closure

```
var instance = this;
var lick = function() {
    alert(instance.paw);
    if(instance.paw == "sticky") {
        alert("meow");
        document.getElementById("catStatus").innerHTML = "*Slurp*";
    }
};
```

Comment: Is that really a closure? It doesn't seem to me to resemble [this description](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml) of a closure. But I'm really not sure.

Comment: Sure it is, it's a closure over the variable `instance` inside the function `lick`.

Answer (score 1):

The context of this depends upon who called the function. In this case it is beCat. You can however explicitly specify the this scope by using call.

In your case:

```
    this.beCat = function () {
        this.paw = "sticky";
        lick.call(this);
    }
```

Or you can store the this in a variable.

You can read more about the this scope/how it works [here](http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/).